# Mapping Multiple Xml Elements to Single Class

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Let us say I have a Xml Like this

```
<person>
<dob>xxxx</dob>
<name>yyyyyy</name>
<phone>zzzzzz</phone>
</person>

<person1>
<dob>xxxx</dob>
<name>yyyyyy</name>
<phone>zzzzzz</phone>
</person1>
```

Is there a way where I Can map person and person1 data to a single class in java

My java code has two seperate classes for person and person1 now

Answer (score 0):

You can declare multiple elements in the annotation. e.g.:

```
@XmlElements({
    @XmlElement(name="person", type=Person.class),
    @XmlElement(name="person1", type=Person.class)
})
List<Person> getPersons() {
    return persons;
}
```

If both elements is available in one document, and you want to display both of them in as one class, you can combine the elements by yourself. e.g.:

```
@XmlElement(name = "person")
public List<Person> getPerson() {
    return person;
}

@XmlElement(name = "person1")
public List<Person> getPerson1() {
    return person1;
}

public List<Person> getPeople() {
    List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
    if(person != null) people.addAll(person);
    if(person1 != null) people.addAll(person1);
    return people;
}
```

Comment: I will try that

Comment: It is only working if it has only one type of Xml Element either person or person1, when both comes together I am getting null value

Comment: When both comes together, you can combine them by yourself. Please check the edited answer, and see if it helps